# zipping rows with columns in SQLalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, typeerror, pyodbc, fetchall

I am converting my library from using pyodbc to SQLalchemy. Unfortunately I am getting this error:

> TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'",)

Here is my function:

```
@route('/api/query/<query>') # not a public system!
def qry(query):
    # `conn` is constructed with `create_engine`
    last_query = conn.execute(query)

    return dict(result=[{zip(last_query._metadata.keys, row)}
                        for row in last_query.fetchall()])
```

And my pyodbc one (which works):

```
    conn.cursor.execute(query)
    return dict(results=[dict(zip([column[0] for column
                                   in conn.cursor.description], row))
                     for row in conn.cursor.fetchall()])
```

Answer (score 1):

The part that's blowing up is

```
{zip(last_query._metadata.keys, row)}
```

The problem is that `{}` syntax won't automatically convert a list of tuples into a dictionary. If you switch to

```
dict(zip(last_query._metadata.keys, row))
```

You should be good to go.

Here's a simplified example in the python shell:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b']
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> {zip(a, b)}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> dict(zip(a, b))
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```